# docker: Why do I access to phpmyadmin?

Tags: docker, apache, phpmyadmin

and excuse me for my English.
I'm using docker in wsl 2 and I have a docker application with three images: laravel, phpmyadmin and mysql

my problem is what I can not access to phpmyadmin.¿can I help me please?
Attached image of the docker application running.

[image]

Whe I tye to access to phpmyadmin, appearc not found page.

[image]

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}' #empty(niether)
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'  #fastfood
            # MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}' #root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}' #empty
            MYSQL_HOST: '${DB_HOST}' #localhost
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: 'phpmyadmin'
        container_name: pma
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: '${DB_HOST}' #localhost
            PMA_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}' #empty(niether)
            PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
```

**information**

windows 10 19052.1052
docker 3.5.1

Comment: Which url do you try to access it with?

Comment: use `adminer` as an alternative to phpmyadmin

Comment: @abhishekphukan thanks for answer mate; the url is ***http://localhost:8081/phpmyadmin***

Comment: @kishore ok, thanks

Comment: Can you try as accessing it with your `machine-ip/phpmyadmin` instead of local host

Comment: @abhishekphukan it does not work either

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://localhost:8081/` instead.

`/phpmyadmin` is just a route that set for the server software like `wamp` for you to access phpmyadmin easily.

Since you have defined in your `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
phpmyadmin:
    image: 'phpmyadmin'
    ...
    ports:
        - 8081:80
    ...
```

which is port `8081`